# Kivy DropDown menu not dropping

Tags: python, android, drop-down-menu, kivy

I am trying to code my very first kivy app as a personal project, but early into development I already encounter one issue: the dropdown menu I was trying to create does not work properly. First of all, here's the code:

```
''' In this early stages of developement, I'm just testing. Probably some method or lines will be changed and/or removed in later commits. -Marco'''


from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    
    # =========== #
    # INIT METHOD #
    # =========== #
    '''
    In order for this code to be reusable, it's reasonable to pass some arguments to the method via __init__:
        
    - "items" is the list of buttons we want in the dropdown menu; it's easier to implement like this instead of hard coding it every time;
    - ...
    
    '''
    def __init__(self, items, **kwargs):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        # Checking that items is a list:
        if not isinstance(items, list):
            raise ValueError(f"The object passed to the method is not of the correct type: it must be a LIST, it's a {str(type(items).__name__).upper()} instead!")
        
        # Defining variables:
        self.items = items
  
  # ================================================================================================================================================================== #  
  
    # ============ #
    # BUILD METHOD #
    # ============ #
    '''
    This method ensures that the layout of the app is as intended. 
    It does not create anything on its own but it sorts everything that the
    other methods will create.
        
    '''
    def build(self):

        # The app will be visualised in vertical instead of horizontal. Maybe 
        #I'll add a way to change with screen orientation but it's a future me problem
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical') 
        
        # Creating the dropdown menu:   
        dropdown = self.create_dropdown(items)
        
        # Creating the main button, the one which generates the dropdown menu:
        main_button = Button(text = "Select Option", size_hint = (1, 1))
        # This next line is the one that actually tells the button to drop the menu:
        main_button.bind(on_release=lambda instance: (print("Opening dropdown..."), dropdown.open(instance)))
        
        dropdown.bind(on_select = lambda instance, x: setattr(main_button, 'text', x))
        
        # Adding the dropdown menu to the layout and defining its behaviour 
        # ("The widget is added to the bottom of the layout if it's being displayed, 
        # or to the top if it's hidden."):
        layout.add_widget(main_button)
        
        return layout
  
  # ================================================================================================================================================================== #  

      
    # ====================== #
    # CREATE DROPDOWN METHOD #
    # ====================== #       
    '''
    This method creates the actual dropdown menu that will be the main way to 
    navigate through the different pages of the balldontlie website. The menu
    will then be displayed as defined in the 'build' method, which calls this 
    function.    
    
    '''
    def create_dropdown(self, items):
        
        print("Create dropdown...") #debug
        # Creating the dropdown variable as a kivy class DropDown's object:
        dropdown = DropDown()
        
        # for loop creating a button for every item in the list. Remember 
        # that a type check is already been done on 'items' in the
        # __init__ method at this point:
        for item in items:
            
            print(f"Creating {item} button...") #debug
            btn = Button(text = item, size_hint_y = None, height = 30) # size_hint_y is None because we want a set position of the button
            # Defining the button behaviour:
            btn.bind(on_release = lambda btn: (dropdown.select(btn.text), print(f"Button {btn.text} pressed.")))
            # Adding the button to the dropdown menu:
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)
         
        print("dropdown created successfully.")    
        return dropdown
            
  # ================================================================================================================================================================== #  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    items = ["Games", "Players", "Teams"]
    MyApp(items).run()
```

As you can see, I already tried to identify the problem with some debug prints, but everything outputs as it should, yet the menu does not drop. Can you identify the error?

I tried tweaking the .bind calls on the dropdown and main button, with no success. The debug prints work as intended, yet I can't solve the issue. This is probably a very basic problem since I'm a beginner but I'm desperate, I've tried them all!

As a side note, I ran this both in and out the kivy virtual environment, getting to the same exact point. Nothing changed at all.

EDIT: I don't know if this can be of any help, but here's the [GitHub repository of my project](https://github.com/CecicOic/Balldontlie.io-Android-Port). It's probably garbage since it's the first one I'm creating that is public and meant for other people to see, but at least the files are there.